# How to work with Visual Studio 2003 and TFS?

Tags: tfs, windows-xp, visual-studio-2003

When I get the latest version of a project (using VS2010) and open the solution in VS2003 it thinks it's checking in and out files, but in reality nothing is changed in the TFS side.

It's very cumbersome checkout every altered file in VS2010's source explorer, edit them in VS2003, and check them in again in VS2010, but I haven't found other solution.

How could I make this easier?

I don't have the time to migrate the solution to a newer version of Visual Studio. It won't work straightaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the MSSCCI provider to connect to TFS from Visual Studio 2003. You can find it on the Visual Studio Gallery [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6/).

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2003 hasn't been generally supported for 5 years at this point, and the extended support ran out earlier this month. I hate to put it like this, but to ensure that your software remains compatible with future updates and operating systems, I think the best option is to try and find why it does not work in VS2010 and fix those issues. Even if you don't think you have the time, making your code compatible with more current technology is a short term investment of time which saves you a lot of time on the long run.

Comment: If nothing else, its certainly time to see just how involved the migration will be. If it is so expensive that you just can't do it right now, then I guess you are stuck with using VS2010 to check in files.